# No right click - open in new tab

Tags: google-chrome

I right click this element in browser on Chrome, and my context menu is different to what is usually seen. I'm missing the open in new tab option. Is this correct? Why is it showing this versus the normal? is there a way to override this?

[image]

Comment: It means the element is not a link.

Comment: @wOxxOm if I left click on the name/element it does take me through to the next page. Is there anyway for that to happen in a new tab?

Comment: It depends on the site. They're not using a link but perform navigation in their script.

Comment: @wOxxOm this is slack in web browser. What affects the ability to do the open in new tab? or anyway you see around it? or anything I could perhaps try out and report back to you :)

Comment: The problem is that slack's programmers violated the UX/accessibility norms by not using the standard link elements. The only way to fix it is to ask them nicely or to write a userscript (or an extension) that will intercept the click and open the URL in a new tab. You'll probably have to reverse-engineer the page code that performs navigation.