# Protractor right click open in a new tab wrong menu proposed

Tags: protractor

I have a problem when I do the test of a right click with Protractor.

The element where I right click is a link ''

However when the test is run in chromeDriver the tab that appears is not a tab that offers the possibility of opening in a new tab.

[image]

It should rather be this

[image]

In protractor I use the following code:

```
 let link = element(by.css('.ag-body-container div[colid="test"] a'));
      await browser.actions().mouseMove(link).perform();
      await browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
      await browser.actions().mouseMove(link).keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).click().perform();
      await browser.actions().mouseMove(link).keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).click().keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL).perform();
```

If you have a solution to this problem
I know that this problem has already been posed but without solution provided

[No right click - open in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60773118/no-right-click-open-in-new-tab)

Comment: Can you please share the snapshot of DOM around this link, the possible problem which looks to me is that while manual click you are clicking exactly on the link that's why you are getting the desired right-click menu, but while automation it is clicking away from the menu leading different right-click menu

Comment: @V.Varshney yes I see what actually meant I agree with you, I have the impression that the right click is not done on the 'a' of the 'href' but before on the column [colid="test"] . Good analysis!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a Single Page App or some similar setup and you are executing the nav clicks with javascript, but you want them to also behave like links.

If so, wrap your navigation item in an `a` tag linking to the link, and prevent executing the link on left click with js

```js
function navClick(event){
  alert("click action");
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="//google.com" onclick="return navClick()"><button>Link</button></a>
```

Hope this helps!